# Restore torrent after OS installation

Tags: system-installation, bittorrent

I have a bunch of torrent files on an external hard drive, downloaded with Transmission (on Elementary OS).

After upgrading / re-installing my OS, I would like Transission to restore the torrent links from the files in my external hard drive.

How can I achieve this? Is it at all possible?

Comment: Try adding the `.torrent` file to Transmission and make sure that the downloaded files are in the right locations. Maybe that'll work.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What do you mean by "adding the `.torrent` file to Transmission"?

Comment: Well when you'd like to torrent you need a `.torrent` file to make all the connections to the other computers. You usually download them from somewhere, open and then start torrenting.

Comment: I usually download a magnet link, but I'm never saving them anywhere, they open in Transmission which then takes care of everything. Where should the links be saved?

Comment: I am afraid if you don't have the torrent file or the magnet link you can't recover it. You need to manually search the torrents on the net.

Comment: How can I make sure henceforth the `.torrent` files will be saved somewhere I can control? I can't see the option to choose the destination file of my magnet links / .torrent files in the preferences.

Comment: You can download and save them somewhere, then open them with Transmission if you really need to save them. Generally torrent files are obsolete after a couple months anyway because there will a new version of the software.